# How to query an ssdp server using java

Tags: java, server, network-programming, ssdp

Is there a way to query a ssdp server using java? I want to send this request using java and then receive the response back from the server and display it. I googled alot but can't find anything on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any solution so I developed my own ([javadoc](https://allen-ball.github.io/javadoc/ball-api/20210415.0/ball/upnp/ssdp/package-summary.html)).  Maven repository and coordinates:

```xml
    <repository>                                                                
      <id>repo.hcf.dev-RELEASE</id>                                             
      <name>hcf.dev RELEASE Repository</name>                                   
      <url>https://repo.hcf.dev/maven/release/</url>                            
      <layout>default</layout>                                                  
    </repository>

      <dependency>                                                              
        <groupId>ball</groupId>                                                 
        <artifactId>ball-upnp</artifactId>                                      
        <version>3.0.2.20210415</version>                                 
      </dependency>
```

Take a look at (or simply run) the [SSDPTask.Discover](https://allen-ball.github.io/javadoc/ball-api/20210415.0/ball/upnp/ant/taskdefs/SSDPTask.Discover.html) Ant Task.